# How DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance() is an example of Abstract factory pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

**What is Abstract Factory Pattern :-**

It provides a way  where a top level factory encapsulate a group of individual factories that are further able to create the family of related products 
without specifying their concrete classes.

As per [Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns) below is cited as  example of Abstract pattern

> `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance()`

But i am not sure how come its following the Abstract Factory Pattern here.

Is `DocumentBuilderFactory` considered as top level factory which internally
cotains individual factory i.e `DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance()` which is able to create the family of related products without specifying their concrete classes (as it just return the `DocumentBuilderFactory` not any specific implementation). Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Reference*

**What is a factory pattern?**

A *Factory method pattern* (aka Factory pattern) is a creational pattern. The creational patterns abstract the object instantiation process by **hiding** how the objects are created and make the system independent of the object creation process.

An **Abstract factory pattern** is one level of abstraction higher than a factory method pattern which means it returns the factory classes.

[image]

### Abstract factory pattern example

**Const**

```
public interface Const {
    public static final int SHAPE_CIRCLE =1;
    public static final int SHAPE_SQUARE =2;
    public static final int SHAPE_HEXAGON =3;
}
```

**ShapeFactory**

```
public abstract class ShapeFactory {
    public abstract Shape getShape(int shapeId);
}
```

In addition to `SimpleShapeFactory` we create new one:

**ComplexShapeFactory**

```
public class ComplexShapeFactory extends ShapeFactory {
    public Shape getShape(int shapeTypeId){
        Shape shape = null;
        if(shapeTypeId == Const.SHAPE_HEXAGON) {
            shape = new Hexagon();//complex shape
        }
        else{
            // drop an error
        };
        return shape;
    }
}
```

Now let’s create at the abstract factory, which returns one of the types of `ShapeFactory`:

**ShapeFactoryType**

```
public class ShapeFactoryType {
    public static final int TYPE_SIMPLE = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_COMPLEX = 2;

    public ShapeFactory getShapeFactory(int type) {
        ShapeFactory sf = null;
        if(type == TYPE_SIMPLE) {
            sf = new SimpleShapeFactory();
        }
        else if (type == TYPE_COMPLEX) {
            sf = new ComplexShapeFactory();
        }
        else throw new BadShapeFactoryException("No factory!!");
        return sf;
    }
}
```

And now the main call:

```
      ShapeFactoryType abFac = new ShapeFactoryType();

    ShapeFactory factory = null;
    Shape s = null;
    //returns a ShapeFactory but whether it is a
    //SimpleShapeFactory or a ComplexShapeFactory is not known to the caller.
    factory = abFac.getShapeFactory(1);//returns SimpleShapeFactory
    //returns a Shape but whether it is a Circle or a Pentagon is
    //not known to the caller.
    s = factory.getShape(2); //returns square.
    s.draw(); //draws a square
    //returns a ShapeFactory but whether it is a
    //SimpleShapeFactory or a ComplexShapeFactory is not
    //known to the caller.
    factory = abFac.getShapeFactory(2);
    //returns a Shape but whether it is a Circle or a Pentagon is
    //not known to the caller.
    s = factory.getShape(3); //returns a pentagon.
    s.draw(); //draws a pentagon
```

### From DocumentBuilderFactory

The `DocumentBuilderFactory` is like `ShapeFactoryType` in example.

The `newInstance(String factoryClassName,ClassLoader classLoader)` returns new instance of a `DocumentBuilderFactory` based on `factoryClassName` (in my case I used `abFac.getShapeFactory(1);` and `abFac.getShapeFactory(2);`).

Comment: My question is how DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance() follwing Abstract factory pattern?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand, is the ShapeFactory superclass abstract?

Comment: @shanehoban yep, I added this class to answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance()` gives you a `DocumentBuilder`, which is a factory for `Document`s.

So `DocumentBuilderFactory` is a factory that produces factories, or in other words, an abstract factory.  This is required because there are many implementations of `DocumentBuilder` depending on JDK version and installed libraries.

Does that clear it up?

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance() gives you DocumentBuilderFactory not DocumentBuilder

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation included in the JDK is `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`, but there are several implementations (factories). e.g.:

- `com.google.gdata.util.common.xml.parsing.SecureGenericXMLFactory`
- `com.icl.saxon.om.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`
- `com.meterware.httpunit.dom.DocumentBuilderFactoryFilter`
- `com.sun.msv.verifier.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`
- `net.sf.saxon.dom.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`
- `org.allcolor.xml.parser.CDocumentBuilderFactory`
- `...`

In order to get the implementation to use (with the method `newInstance()`), in the javadoc of [`javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) you can read:

> Obtain a new instance of a `DocumentBuilderFactory`. This static method creates a new factory instance. This method uses the following ordered lookup procedure to determine the `DocumentBuilderFactory` **implementation class to load**:
>
> - Use the `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` system property.
> - Use the properties file `"lib/jaxp.properties"` in the JRE directory. This configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties format and contains the fully qualified name of the implementation class with the key being the system property defined above. The `jaxp.properties` file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and it's values are then cached for future use. If the file does not exist when the first attempt is made to read from it, no further attempts are made to check for its existence. It is not possible to change the value of any property in `jaxp.properties` after it has been read for the first time.
> - Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for a classname in the file `META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` in jars available to the runtime.
> - Platform default `DocumentBuilderFactory` instance.
>
> Once an application has obtained a reference to a `DocumentBuilderFactory` it can use the factory to configure and obtain parser instances.

Comment: but how DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance() following Abstract factory pattern?

Comment: The method returns a factory specifically, depending on the configuration of the virtual machine. And each factory has its concrete classes.

Comment: In that case My Understanding seems to be correct.Is n't it? Here is my understanding  :-  DocumentBuilderFactory considered as top level factory which internally cotains individual factory i.e DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance() which is able to create the family of related products without specifying their concrete classes (as it just return the DocumentBuilderFactory not any specific implementation). Is this correct?

Comment: You are right! This class uses the design pattern. To use an implementation, just configure it and go!